# Show Images from another Project in Xamarin forms

Tags: image, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to display the photos in the folder "Images" directly on a
Image object (In AdProject). But this folder is in another project in my solution(In AdWebApi).

Does anyone know how I can do this?

In the Microsoft documentation, it says that it can be done this way:

MyImage.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("AdWebApi.Images.filename.png", typeof(...)?.GetType().Assembly);

[Images Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQPmT.png)

But as you can see, the image folder in another project is in the same solution. How can I display images from it?

How can I get the project's (AdWebApi) Assembly ?

It may not be a logical question, but it's for my information only

Comment: does AdProject contain a reference to AdWebApi?

Answer (score 0):

From this article Images [embedded in other projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#images-embedded-in-other-projects), I create two project in one solution, one is **imageapp**, another is **mediasample**.

I add one image in **imageapp.Images** folder, set to Build Action: **EmbeddedResource**. then building this project.

Finally, right-click another project mediasample **Dependencies**, choose **Add Project Reference....** , choose imageapp dll.

[image]

now you can get image from other project.

```
image1.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("imageapp.Images.waterfront.jpg", typeof(imageapp.MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
```

If you add WebAPi in project, right-click another project mediasample Dependencies, choose Add Project Reference.... , click **Browse**, add **System.Web dll** by
**C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.1**

[image]